# Adding values and strings in Matplotlib subplot texts

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, subplot

I'm new to programming so this is a basic question. I am creating a number of subplots in a big loop and wish to annotate each one with both a description and a value for that plot, e.g. Alpha = 5. But I find that using `ax.text` I can create one part or the other, but not both. The following code snippet produces roughly the desired outcome, but only when I run ax.text twice and position them manually, which of course is impractical.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
i=0
for alpha,beta in [(5,10),(100,20)]:
    for omega in ['A','B']:
        i+=1
        ax=plt.subplot(2,2,i)
        ax.text(0.1,0.9,'Alpha = ')
        ax.text(0.25,0.9,alpha)

plt.show()
```

I've tried various combinations of commas, plus signs and indices in `ax.text` but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
i=0
for alpha,beta in [(5,10),(100,20)]:
    for omega in ['A','B']:
        i+=1
        ax=plt.subplot(2,2,i)
        ax.text(0.1,0.9,'Alpha = {}'.format(alpha))
plt.show()
```

Using formatting to do this